# How to use Comparator for duplicates?

Tags: java, comparator, classcastexception

I'm new in Java and try to make a comparator that will sort objects from Min to Max, and in case of duplicates, will send them to the end of the list to get as a result something like [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, and so on]. But even this initial variant is not working!? I get a ClassCastException that Integer cannot be cast to TestArr. Wher is a mistake? Here is my code:

```
public class IntraArrayValuesComparison {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> num1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
        num1.add(40);
        num1.add(50);
        num1.add(50);
        num1.add(40);
        num1.add(20);
        num1.add(10);
        num1.add(10);
        num1.add(30);
        num1.add(20);
        num1.add(30);

    Collections.sort(num1, new ArraysValuesCompare());
    Iterator itr = num1.iterator();  
    while (itr.hasNext()) {  
        TestArr st = (TestArr)itr.next();  
        System.out.println(st.var);
        }
    System.out.println();
}
}

class TestArr {
int var;
TestArr (int var) {
    this.var = var;
}
}

class ArraysValuesCompare implements Comparator{
public int compare (Object o1, Object o2){
    TestArr a = (TestArr)o1;
    TestArr b = (TestArr)o2;
    if (a.var >= b.var)
        return 0;  
    else  
        return 1;  
        }
}
```

Comment: `itr.next();` will return the next `Integer` in `num1`. Why are you trying to cast that to a `TestArr` object?

Comment: If you're just trying to print the contents you can just do `for(Integer num: num1) {System.out.println(num);}`

Comment: Also you have an `ArrayList` of `Integer`'s that you're comparing as `TestArr` objects.

Comment: You should use Generics consistently. If you implemented your comparator as `Comparator<TestArr>`, the compiler told you that it is not possible to use it to sort a list of **`Integer`** instances. Further, your comparator is broken. It should return zero if and only if the values are equal. Otherwise, the sign of the returned number should reflect whether the first or the second argument is bigger. If in doubt, just use `return Integer.compare(a.var, b.var);` which does the job for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I never used comparators and this one is a variant I've did after studied several examples that I could find. I'm not even sure why should I use the "class TestArr{...}"!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class IntraArrayValuesComparison {
    private static boolean isInRange(Integer st, Integer val) {
        final int DELTA = 5;
        return val.intValue() >= (st.intValue() - DELTA) && val.intValue() <= (st.intValue() + DELTA);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getDeckWithLessCards(List<List<Integer> > resultDecks) {
        if(resultDecks.isEmpty())
            return new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> cards = resultDecks.get(0);
        for(int i= 1; i < resultDecks.size(); ++i) {
            if(resultDecks.get(i).size() < cards.size())
                cards = resultDecks.get(i);
        }
        return cards;
    }

    private static Collection<List<Integer> > sort(List<Integer> deck, Integer splitSize) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> decks = new TreeMap<>();
        outerLoop:
        for(Integer card : deck) {
            List<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterator<Integer> itr = decks.keySet().iterator();  
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Integer masterCard = itr.next(); 
                if(isInRange(card, masterCard)) {                   
                    decks.get(masterCard).add(card);
                    continue outerLoop;
                }
            }
            decks.put(card, cards);
            decks.get(card).add(card);
        }

        System.out.println("Arranged decks:\t" + decks.values());
        //do transpose
        List<List<Integer> > resultDecks = new ArrayList<>();
        if(splitSize == null || splitSize < 2)
            splitSize = decks.size();
        for(int i= 0; i < splitSize; ++i)
            resultDecks.add(new ArrayList<>());

        boolean lastCard = false;
        while(!decks.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Integer> itr = decks.keySet().iterator(); 
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                Integer masterCard = itr.next(); 
                List<Integer> cards = decks.get(masterCard);
                Integer card = Collections.min(cards);
                cards.remove(card);
                boolean uno = cards.isEmpty();
                if(uno) {
                    lastCard = true;
                    getDeckWithLessCards(resultDecks).add(card);
                    itr.remove();
                }               
                else if(lastCard) {
                    resultDecks.get(0).add(card);
                    lastCard = false;
                }
                else
                    getDeckWithLessCards(resultDecks).add(card);
            }           
        }
        return resultDecks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = null;
        System.out.print("Please input data (1, 5, 10, 2, 15, 3, 20): ");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            data = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect data format.");
            return;
        }

        if(data == null || data.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect data format.");
            return;
        }

        List<Integer> deck = new ArrayList<>();  
        for(String value : data)
            deck.add(new Integer(value.trim()));

        Collection<List<Integer> > resultDecks = sort(deck, 3);
        System.out.println("Final decks:\t" + resultDecks);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It looks amaizing and really works. I've tried to do this for almost a month, but now I see that I will never do this without your help. Can you suggest a solution or at least give an advise on how to slice the resulted sorted array into several smaller arrays? The quantity of arrays should be a user defined option.

Comment: This may not work as you expected for [1,3,5,7,9] and [5,3,1,7,9]. Are you asking for algorithms like k-means clustering?

Comment: It's not a task for cluster analysis. In fact what I need is to divide an array into several parts. Quantity of parts would depend on the quantity of similar values within initial array, because each "similar value" should go to different subArrays. For example if my initial array is [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20], and the "similar values" are consideried to be [1, 2 and 3] then there should be created three subArrays, but unequal size, with the values [1, 5, 10], [2, 15] and [3, 20].

Comment: You helped me to sort array in specific mode like [1, 5, 10, 2, 15, 3, 20], now I need to slice it into parts. My knowlege is let me to create only a List<List<Integer>> that contains three arrays but they are identical [[1, 5, 10] [1, 5, 10] [1, 5, 10]]. And I can't understand why they are identical and how to do them different.

Comment: To sum up, after grouping the cards with similar values into several decks, it is required to do a transpose. All players giving a card with ascending order (like playing card game Hearts) to the new deck which containing minimum number of cards. When a player comes to UNO, next player put the card with least value to the first new deck.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a `Comparator`.

But you can sort the values and then rearrange the values, i.e. repeatedly moving duplicates to the end of the list, like you said.

```
public static List<Integer> sortAscendingRepeated(Integer... values) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    Collections.sort(list);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1)))
            list.add(list.remove(i--));
    return list;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(sortAscendingRepeated(40, 50, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 30, 20, 30));
System.out.println(sortAscendingRepeated(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4));
```

*Output*

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's looks very nice and easy, but how correctly apply it for already created ArrayList num1, which store user-entered values?

Comment: @SergeiVoychuk Just pass that list in as the parameter. I just did the varargs parameter because it was easier to test.

Comment: I did next: public static List<ArrayList<Integer>> sortAscendingRepeated(ArrayList<Integer> num1) {
  Collections.sort(num1); ... }. And: System.out.println(sortAscendingRepeated(num1)). Finally result is [[10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50]]. What's wrong?

Comment: As I understand, in this case a sorted num1 array was inserted into a new array without any calculations.

Comment: @SergeiVoychuk If you pass in the `List<Integer>` to be updated, why would return type change to `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`? The updated list is still a `List<Integer>`, so that should still be the return type, or since the list given in the parameter would be updated the return type could be changed to `void`.

Comment: Because, when I try to use List<Integer> only my Eclipse does not want to recognise Arrays.asList(num1) command and propose to change a type of List to List<ArrayList<Integer>>.

Comment: What `Arrays.asList` command? If you pass in the list to be sorted, instead of a varargs array, there would be no need to create a list from an array, would there?

Comment: So much I have to study. Ok, I've tried to use the next: public static List<Integer> sortAscendingRepeated(List<Integer> num1) {
  Collections.sort(num1);
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1)))
            list.add(list.remove(i--));
       }
     return list;
 }. The result of this is an empty array [ ]!?

Comment: @SergeiVoychuk Of course it's empty, you just created it. --- Why `new ArrayList`? You change the parameter from `Integer... values` to `List<Integer> list`, and remove the first statement. That's it! Do you understand at all what the code is actually doing?

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my questions, I'm new in Java and was sure that Array.asList should be used in this case to give values from ArrayList num1 to a new List list. Now I tried addAll command and everything is Ok.

Comment: Can I ask your advise in two more questions? After this I have to slice this array into several smaller parts and I know how to do it manually indicating everytime start and end indexes, but I need it to be carried out automatically. So, the first question is: is it reasonable to use a loop to generate fresh ArrayLists of smaller sizes, or should it be somthing other? And, second, after all I need to add new values to the freshly made small-arrays, so should I generate ArrayLists or subList is Ok too, which of these two will be a right choice?

Comment: Oh, I've just realized that I have no necessity even to create a fresh List list, but directly sort num1!!!

Answer (score 0):

A histogram map can be used for consolidation and counting.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class IntraArrayValuesComparison {

    private static void sort(List<TestArr> num1) {
        Map<TestArr, Integer> histogram = new TreeMap<TestArr, Integer>();
        for(TestArr test : num1) {
            Integer count = histogram.get(test);
            if(count == null)
                count = 0;
            histogram.put(test, ++count);
        }

        num1.clear();
        while(!histogram.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<TestArr> itr = histogram.keySet().iterator();  
            while (itr.hasNext()) {  
                TestArr st = itr.next(); 
                Integer count = histogram.get(st);
                if(count > 0) {
                    num1.add(st);
                    histogram.put(st, --count);
                    continue;
                }
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestArr> num1 = new ArrayList<>();     
        num1.add(new TestArr(40));
        num1.add(new TestArr(50));
        num1.add(new TestArr(50));
        num1.add(new TestArr(40));
        num1.add(new TestArr(20));
        num1.add(new TestArr(10));
        num1.add(new TestArr(10));
        num1.add(new TestArr(30));
        num1.add(new TestArr(20));
        num1.add(new TestArr(30));

        sort(num1);

        Iterator<TestArr> itr = num1.iterator();  
        while (itr.hasNext()) {  
            TestArr st = itr.next();  
            System.out.println(st.var);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

class TestArr implements Comparable<TestArr> {
    Integer var;
    TestArr (int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestArr o) {
        if(o == null)
            return -1;
        return var.compareTo(o.var);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice solution. I have never heared about histogram maps.  Why the values were added into the num1 as a new TestArr values: "num1.add(new TestArr(40));"? Can I directly use num1 values from ArrayList?

Comment: A histogram is an accurate representation of the distribution of numerical data. It is used to filter the duplicated ones and records the frequency count. Remove the class TestArr and replace all TestArr to Integer to directly use num1 values.

Comment: It's really works. Thank you. But It compares value to value by their exact match, and how to change the assumption if I have to consider that values that did not differ on 5, for example, are all the same and move them in the end of the list. For example if I have a list [10, 11, 13, 15, 20, 21, 23, 30, 31], can I make a fresh list [10, 20, 30, 11, 21, 31, 13, 23, 15]. That is every time the values are checked for their similarity in some range (+/-5 in this case).